# What is meaning of this number label

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently I saw this like "Count label" on tabs of SourceTree. What is this meaning do you know?

I already search for that on the internet. But I couldn't find the specific information.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with a git status in command line: this might be the number of commit you are ahead/behind compared to your remote repository.

In your case: 3 local commits not yet pushed.

Note: the tabs in SourceTree 2.x [sparked a "lively" debate](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-discussions/New-2-0-tab-interface-unusable/td-p/582304): (as in "people hated it"), and the recent SourceTree 3.x still has issues [SRCTREEWIN-7176](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7176).

Comment: Oh Thank you for your information promptly. I will search it on the internet.

Comment: oh I accepted this answer. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: @Ichiro Thenk you. Check also your older questions: some of them might have good answers that you could accept.